# Finding Eigenvalues with a Variable in the Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, eigenvalue

I'd like to preface this by saying i have some knowledge in python, but this stuff is above the type of things i know/ have an understanding of.

So I have a system of equations;
u = -(x1) + (x2) and v = -2(x1) + (x2)^2; where x1 and x2 are variables

and I have to find the eigenvalues of the jacobian via python. I was able to get a matrix for the jacobian using this code:

```
def Jacobian(v_str, f_list):
    vars = sym.symbols(v_str)
    f = sym.sympify(f_list)
    J = sym.zeros(len(f),len(vars))
    for i, fi in enumerate(f):
        for j, s in enumerate(vars):
            J[i,j] = sym.diff(fi, s)
    return J

matrix = Jacobian('x1 x2', ['-x1 + x2','-2*x1 - x2**2'])
```

honestly I found this code online so there are a few things i don't completely under stand from it, but the matrix i got from here equals the matrix I got on paper.

now the problem starts here, the matrix I get is ([-1,1], [-2,-2(x2)]). So i went digging online on how to code for to get the eigenvalues of this matrix, and i come across the codes `np.linalg.eigvals(matrix)` and `import scipy.linalg as la` + `results = la.eig(A)`.

however when I try this, i get the error `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''` (for the first method) and `ValueError: object arrays are not supported` (second method).

I more or less get that the reason these errors are happening are probably due to the -2(x2) term in the matrix, but I haven't been able to find any solution to how to deal with a variable, so any help with this would be welcomed and appreciated.

I believe I covered all my bases, I am using python 3.8 (via spyder/anaconda) and if any more information is required, please let me know.

Comment: It seems you want to have an algebraic solution. This means you need to use a library that can do symbolic (algebraic) computations. As far as I am aware humpy and scipy both do not support that, they are exclusively for numerical computations. If you want to solve this using python I think you need to look into *sympy*. Otherwise I recommend using any CAS of your choise. There is for instance the free *maxima*.

Comment: @flawr I'm sorry, i'm not sure of what CAS stands for. But thank you! i'm assuming that there is nothing wrong with the math done for finding the jacobian matrix (i'm assuming since you didn't mention it).

Comment: CAS stands for *computer algebra system*